# HyperTrackViews failed to query MovementStatus

Tags: ios, hypertrack

Calling `hyperTrackViews.subscribeToMovementStatusUpdates` in iOS, get the error 'HyperTrackViews failed to query MovementStatus'

```
cancelSubscription = hyperTrackViews.subscribeToMovementStatusUpdates(for: deviceIDhtk) { [weak self] result in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    
    print("hptmovementResultSubs::", result)
    
    switch result {
    case let .success(movementStatus):
        print("hptmovementStatusSubs::", movementStatus)
        if let trip = movementStatus.trips.first {
            print("hptmovementStatusTrip",movementStatus.trips)
        } else {
            print("hptmovementStatusTripElse",movementStatus.trips)
        }
        
    case .failure(let error):
        dump(error)
        print("hptmovementStatusSubsError::",error)
    }
}
```